# Windows 8.1 will not go back to sleep after waking up

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sleep, screensaver, wake-up

I have problems putting Windows to sleep and starting the screen saver on my new Windows 8.1 machine.

Sleep mode and screen savers work only when the computer is first powered up (or restarted). But once it goes to sleep (manually or automatically) and I wake it up later, it wont go back to sleep again and I can't use screen savers either.

I updated the chipset and graphics card drivers. My computer isn't part of a homegroup either.
Does anyone else have similar issues?

Thanks for your advice, 
per

Answer (score 1):

Start the command prompt (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → "cmd" → OK) and use this command to check what sleep states are available for your computer:

```
powercfg -a
```

If it doesn't say `Hybrid Sleep` in the list of available sleep states, you might need to update your graphics card drivers.

If that doesn't help, [try running the troubleshooter and troubleshoot for power related problems](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/sleep-mode-not-working-windows-8-1)

As for the screensaver issues, you [might want to look into this](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-2082913/windows-screensaver-working.html). Some users seem to be facing these problems after installing Windows Update 2756872. If you have that update installed, try uninstalling it to see if that fixes the issues.

### Update

This solution will enable Windows machines (Vista or later) to start a batch file after resuming from sleep (possibly hibernation as well). The script will use PsShutdown to put the computer back to sleep after waiting for 15 minutes.

1. Download and install [`Hibernate Trigger`](http://www.desimonesystems.com/suspendtrigger/index.php) and [`PsShutdown`](http://live.sysinternals.com/psshutdown.exe). Run PsShutdown at least once and agree to the license agreement.
2. Move `psshutdown.exe` to the folder where `Hibernate Trigger` is installed
3. Edit the `suspend.ini` file present in the folder (open it using Notepad) and make sure it contains the following lines:

```
Suspend=
Resume=GoToSleepAgain.bat
Minimize=YES
```

4. Create a batch file in the folder called `GoToSleepAgain.bat` and add the following lines in the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM increase the timeout value if you need the computer to wait for more than 15 minutes
timeout /T 900
psshutdown -d -t 0
```

5. Start `HibernateTrigger.exe`. Make sure that it is running in the system tray. You might want to test it out by putting the computer to sleep manually and then waking it up again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it did not helped. I have Hybrid Sleep in powercfg -a list. I don't have Update 2756872 installed and troubleshooter did not helped.

Comment: Do you see a "Sleep" option under power options when your computer wakes up from sleep mode?

Comment: Yes and I can put computer to sleep manually.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Do you see a "Sleep" option *after* your computer has woken up from sleep mode which was triggered manually or automatically?

Comment: Yes, and I can manually trigger it. Problem is, that "sleep" will not trigger automatically after first wake up from sleep.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution also does not work. It triggers sleep, if I am using my computer, too. And it can't turn off screen.

Comment: You need to exit the application when you don't want your computer to go to sleep while you're using it. And by the way, you said "it triggers sleep" and that "it can't turn off screen" so are you saying that when it puts your computer to sleep, it does so without the monitor turning off?

Comment: OK. When it goes to sleep it turns off monitor, but I meant "turn off the screen" option without sleep.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your problem yet. You'll need to be more specific and provide more details (a list of all the issues you're facing, the stuff you've tried, what seems to work and what doesn't and also provide a detailed report on what happens when you try my solution)

Comment: There are 3 "power options" in Windows: Screensaver (but I don't need it), turn off display after some time (I have 10 minutes timer for that) and sleep after some time. After restarting my computer, all of these trigger automatically, but after first wake up, none of these will trigger automatically. I tried leave update drivers, leave homegroup (I did not have any), disable IPv6 and all your suggestions. Problem with your last suggestion is, that it will not turn off display after some time.

Comment: You could turn the screen off using [Dark](https://dark.codeplex.com/). Install it and start the program, then double click its icon in the system tray and your computer screen should go dark.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I much rather fixed Windows native functions, but this will do what I need.